# Should I hide my facebook app_id and secret_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, koala

I am done creating my first facebook app in ruby on rails. In my controller I have somethign like

```
 @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id,secret_id,callback_url) (Replaced with temp values)
```

I am wondering is it okay to have these values in my controller or should I hide it somewhere else in my app? Assigning them to variables?

What's the right programming habit here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really comes down to wanting to avoid recording these values in your version control system.

The approach I usually take is as follows:

Add the following to your `config/application.rb`, inside the application class definition

```
# Loads app config from /config/env_vars.yml
require 'yaml'
rails_root = Rails.root || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
config = YAML.load_file(rails_root.to_s + '/config/env_vars.yml')
if config.key?(Rails.env) && config[Rails.env].is_a?(Hash)
  config[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
    ENV[key] = value.to_s
  end
end
```

Create a file in `config/` called `env_vars.yml`, and include the following

```
development:
  FB_APP_ID: APP_ID_HERE
  FB_APP_SECRET: APP_SECRET_HERE
```

replacing `APP_ID_HERE` and `APP_SECRET_HERE` with your api details. Add as many other values to this file as required (i.e. Twitter keys etc), and repeat for each environment (e.g. if you have different FB apps for dev, staging and production). These can then be referenced by in your controller as `ENV['FB_APP_ID']` etc.

If using this approach, you can leave the env_vars.yml out of your VCS, thus meaning that you have not actually committed these values to your repository, while still making them available to your app.

---

Finally, if you use Heroku, assigning these values as environmental variables is easy to do for each app (i.e. `heroku config:set FB_APP_ID=234234324234` - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars for more details), saving the need to commit these values to the repo before pushing up to Heroku.

#### N.B. If using Heroku, there are a couple of modifications to the above approach

If excluding `env_vars.yml` from git, this file will not be available when pushed to Heroku, causing your app to crash on boot. The simplest solution is to modify the code added to `config/application.rb` as follows:

```
# Loads app config from /config/env_vars.yml
unless Rails.env == 'production'
  require 'yaml'
  rails_root = Rails.root || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
  config = YAML.load_file(rails_root.to_s + "/config/env_vars.yml")
  if config.key?(Rails.env) && config[Rails.env].is_a?(Hash)
    config[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
      ENV[key] = value.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

By wrapping it in the `unless Rails.env == 'production'` conditional, it will be skipped if running on `production` (the default environment for Heroku). If using multiple environments for Heroku (such as `staging`, `uat`, `production`) this could be modified to

```
unless %w(staging uat production).include?(Rails.env)
```

Once this has been committed and pushed to Heroku, it will no longer be looking for the `env_vars.yml` file, leaving you free to set your config variables an an app-by-app basis via the `heroku config:set` Heroku toolbelt command.

Comment: Spacing and indentation is quite important in yml files, and it could have been broken by the markup on Stack Exchange. Take a look at the database.yml file in your config folder and copy the formatting from that, which might resolve the error.

Comment: yep I finally figured it out. So i deleted my comments. thanks though :D.

Comment: Hi again, because of the above code. My app crashes in heroku. Coz, its not able to find env_var.yml file. Since I hid it using .gitignore. Is there a way around it? That is only run it in development and not in production?

Comment: Or how do i leave env_vars.yml out of my VCS/git. Sorry I didnt get that part.?

Comment: Updated - let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this article: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-environment-variables.html

I prefer using figaro gem: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro